# How to solve MySQL privileges probelem

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am super new of using phpAdmin, when I create a table it shows :

```
#1142 - CREATE command denied to user 'id6460855_haochen273'@'2a02:4780:bad:c0de::14' for table 'users'
```

I tried to use:

```
mysql> GRANT
SELECT,
INSERT,
UPDATE,
DELETE,
CREATE,
DROP ON systest.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
```

`Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)`

But I still get same errors in phpAdmin, Is there any problems I need to solve?

Comment: Could provide the error log?

Comment: create and drop are system privilege. I'm not how you can use both object and system privilege in the same grant.

Comment: You are trying to set privillege to user root . Your error shows that the user id6460855_haochen273 does not have any privillege to access  so try to set privillege for the user id6460855_haochen273.

Answer (score 1):

Your query wasn't quite correct. You aren't the root user via phpmyadmin, look at the user in the error code. Also, you put the password as `root`, maybe that's the password, but I wasn't sure, so I clarified in my statement where the password goes.

```
mysql> GRANT
SELECT,
INSERT,
UPDATE,
DELETE,
CREATE,
DROP ON systest.* TO 'id6460855_haochen273'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PUT A PASSWORD HERE';
```